# SQL Query para contagem de valores únicos em uma coluna

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, count, distinct

Preciso contar os valores únicos da coluna FORNECEDOR da tabela abaixo. **O Resultado esperado é 22**, porém as funções COUNT não tem apresentado o resultado esperado.

A tabela que contém a coluna em questão é:

[image: Resultado da query]

A query dessa tabela é:

```
SELECT
SUM(CAST(c.filial AS INT)) AS 'FIL', a.codpro AS 'COD', a.descr AS 'DESCRIÇÃO', SUM(CAST(c.quant AS INT)) AS 'EST', 
b.nome AS fornecedor, d.nome AS disponobilidade, a.comprador AS 'COMPRADOR'

FROM produtocad a, fornececad b, itemfilest c, item d

    WHERE a.codpro = c.codpro
    AND a.codfor = b.oid
    AND a.disponibilidade = '21073'
    AND a.comprador = '03'
    AND d.oid = a.disponibilidade

        GROUP BY a.codpro, a.descr, b.nome, a.disponibilidade, a.comprador, d.nome

            HAVING SUM(CAST(c.quant AS INT)) <= 0

                ORDER BY b.nome
```

Ao utilizar as funções COUNT, os resultados obtidos são:

=>  COUNT(DISTINCT b.nome)

[image: Resultado da query count distinct]

=> COUNT(b.nome) ou COUNT(*) ou COUNT(1)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como obter o resultado 22?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando da dica do nosso amigo *imex*, fica aqui minha contribuíção completa para seu SQL. Resolvi colocar um *SELECT* um nivel acima, pois em alguns casos as funções de janeja (com uso do *OVER()*) acabam não funcionanando bem com o *GROUP BY* no mesmo nível.

Além disso o *ORDER BY* também foi movido para o nível mais alto da consulta, para que não sofra influência do *OVER()*.

```
select 
    d.*,
    count(distinct d.fornecedor) over() 'TOTAL_FORNECEDORES'
from
    (
        SELECT
            SUM(CAST(c.filial AS INT)) AS 'FIL', 
            a.codpro AS 'COD', 
            a.descr AS 'DESCRIÇÃO', 
            SUM(CAST(c.quant AS INT)) AS 'EST', 
            b.nome AS fornecedor, 
            d.nome AS disponobilidade, 
            a.comprador AS 'COMPRADOR'
        FROM 
            produtocad a, 
            fornececad b, 
            itemfilest c, 
            item d
        WHERE a.codpro = c.codpro
            AND a.codfor = b.oid
            AND a.disponibilidade = '21073'
            AND a.comprador = '03'
            AND d.oid = a.disponibilidade
        GROUP BY 
            a.codpro, 
            a.descr, 
            b.nome, 
            a.disponibilidade, 
            a.comprador, 
            d.nome
            HAVING SUM(CAST(c.quant AS INT)) <= 0
    ) d
ORDER BY 
    d.nome
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Evandro, porém retornou o mesmo erro da resposta anterior: Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause. Retirando o DISTINCT retorna 224.

Comment: Consegui! Colocando um SELECT um nível acima como você fez e retirando o OVER retornou 22. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi o resultado seria 22 considerando todas as linhas retornadas pela consulta. Se for isso mesmo, experimente acrescentar a clausula Over na frente da função Count, pois sem ela será retornada somente a quantidade de cada agrupamento:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT b.nome) OVER()
```

Comment: Você entendeu corretamente, porém ao usar o OVER retornou esse erro: Use of DISTINCT is not allowed with the OVER clause. 

Retirando o distinct, retorna 224.